# which method is fired when notification turned off by user - iphone

Tags: iphone, push-notification

when a user chooses to allow push notifications then the following method gets invoked:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

but if s/he choose not to allow the notification which method is called?
also if a user decided to allow notification and after a while to turned them off - which method is called?

Answer (score 0):

When application generates a pop up to ask user for permissions to receive push notification, on success device receives access token and goes to method didRegisterForRemoteNotification.But if user disallow then device fails to get device token and goes to method.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
```